# Insistent notification on Android Wear

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

[Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_INSISTENT) works on my Android device. Notification vibrates and sounds repeatedly. However it only vibrates once on my Android Wear.

I have followed the Android Developer guide to create an Android Wear notification, but no luck. https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

I want the effect of the stock Android Alarm Clock app's notification.

Any hint before I dig into the [source code of the app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Android Wear app to your existing project. Vibrate the watch with the [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) class there.
Note: The package names of both the handheld device app and Wear app must be the same.

Reference: http://dejan.djurovski.net/2014/10/02/adding-an-android-wear-component-to-an-existing-android-studio-project/